# Bulk append one word in front of all product names in store

Tags: magento2

I have magento 2.3.4 and trying to append one word to all products. Is it possible to do using standard M2 means or phpmyadmin?

Correction, I only need to append names for items with certain attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can mass / bulk update the collection of products in multiple ways as given below.

**`#1 Through Magento Product Import Export from the admin panel`**

At first `export all the products` from your store, by using the `export` option available under the admin menu `System - Data Transfer - Export`

Then edit the CSV file and update the `name` column of all the product rows by appending a string/text of your choice to the `name` column. (there are easy ways to do this in MS Excel)

keep only the `sku` and `name` columns and `import the csv` to get the product names updated

For further reference about Magento2 product import and export, check these links below

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-import.html

https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-product-import-export.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-import-products-magento-2.html

**`#2 Update the product names through a Custom Script`**

its the quickest and get the job done in a few minutes

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errros',1);
ini_set('memory_limit',-1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$ObjectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $ObjectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$attributeSetId = 184; 

$_productCollection = $ObjectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',$attributeSetId)
                        ->load(); 

$_productAction = $ObjectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action');
$storeId = 1; // change it your store id
$stringToAppend = 'TEST-';

try {
    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
        $productName = $stringToAppend . $_product->getName();
        echo 'Name: ' . $_product->getName() . PHP_EOL; 
        echo 'Name to be changed : ' . $productName . PHP_EOL; 
//        
        $productIds = [];
        $attributeData = [];
        $attributeData['name'] =  $productName;
        $productIds[] = $_product->getId();
        
        /* it is recommended to use updateAttributes in case of bulk product updates */
        $_productAction->updateAttributes($productIds,$attributeData,$storeId);
        
        /* You can also use save() which is slower than the above method  */
//        $_product->setName($productName)
//                ->save();
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Product Save Exception : ' . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

$_productCollectionAfterUpdate = $ObjectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
                                                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))
                                                ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',$attributeSetId)
                                                ->load(); 
                        
foreach ($_productCollectionAfterUpdate as $_product) {
    echo 'Name after appending string : ' . $_product->getName() . PHP_EOL; 
}
```

> **Disclaimer: Use of ObjectManager Directly is highly discouraged in a
> production environment. Inject the dependencies in the respective
> class instead.**

Comment: thank you, I was looking for that php method. I forgot to mention that it should apply onoy to products with a certain attribute set. $attributeId = 184

Comment: @AlexD updated the answer with attribute set filter, which filters the product collection based on the given attribute set id